# Использование расширения

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте. Подключил к проекту расширение yii-user. Лежит в папке modules/user.
Все вроде работает.
В расширении имеется класс WebUser от CWebUser. Я дописал свой метод isAdmin().
В рамках расширения я его использую так: Yii::app()->user->isAdmin(), а когда я хочу вызвать в основном приложении, то получаю "Error 500. В классе CWebUser и его поведениях не найден метод или замыкание с именем "isAdmin"."
Получается, что в основном приложении он как бы не подключен.
В config/main.php:

```
    'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.user.models.*',
    'application.modules.user.components.*',
),
```

Как подключить его так, чтоб можно было использовать классы расширения в основном приложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается забыл добавить в конфиг:

```
    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        #...
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'class' => 'WebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
        ),
        #...
    ),
```

Comment: Исходя из названия isAdmin(), посмотрите на
http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/access.rbac.file

Comment: @dekameron, спасибо за ссылку. Но у меня только админ и юзер) Пока обойдусь функциями.